# Duplicated Mongo Document Has No _id in Save Callback Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and mongo, and I need some help. I'm attempting to duplicate existing documents in Mongo using node.js and mongoose.

My process for this is:

1. Find the document that will be duplicated.
2. Create a new Schema object, passing in the first document's schema object, which was retrieved in step one.
3. Delete the '_id' property of the object created in step two.
4. Save the new object.

This works fine. The problem is that I need to have another document type, that holds an id as a reference to this type of document. In the success callback, the object passed in has no value for the '_id' field. This is where I'm attempting to grab it to save in the other document. But, when I check the database, the document was successfully saved and does in fact have an '_id'.

Can someone shed some light on what is going on here, or perhaps where I am misunderstanding this process.

**Here is my code:**
In the Controller:

```
          async.each(cards, function(card, nextCard) {¬
¬
            var newCard = new Card(card);¬
            newCard.story_id = story._id;¬
            newCard.linkedElements = [];¬
¬
            newCard._id = null;¬
            delete newCard._id;¬
            // The id has been removed to avoid¬
            // duplicates in mongo.¬
¬
            newCard.save(function(err, savedCard) {¬
¬
              if (err) {¬
                console.log('err', err);¬
                process.exit();¬
              }¬
              // There were no errors.¬
¬
              // The current card was duplicated.¬
¬
              Element¬
                .find({'card_id': card._id}, function(err, elements) {¬
¬
                if (err) {¬
                  console.log('err', err);¬
                  process.exit();¬
                }¬
                // There were no errors.¬
¬
                async.each(elements, function(element, nextElement) {¬
¬
                  var newElement = new Element();¬
¬
                  console.log('New card : ', newCard);¬
                  console.log('Saved card : ', savedCard);¬
¬
                  newElement.card_id = savedCard._id;¬
                  ** I BELIEVE THIS IS THE PROBLEM! **
¬
                  newElement._id = null;¬
                  delete newElement._id;¬
                  // The id has been removed to avoid¬
                  // duplicates in mongo.
```

The Output from the console log and node:

```
New card :  { story_id: 53f0e8f3c45582e00927a501,
  rank: 1,
  published: 'true',
  __v: 0,
  _id: null,
  linkedElements: [] }
Saved card :  { story_id: 53f0e8f3c45582e00927a501,
  rank: 1,
  published: 'true',
  __v: 0,
  _id: null,
  linkedElements: [] }
POST /admin/stories/duplicate/53f0e4c1c973f73b08942591 200 18ms - 277b
err { [VersionError: No matching document found.] message: 'No matching document found.', name: 'VersionError' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why it worked at all. When you call `.save()` on `mongoose` document it issue an `update` operation sending only updated fields to MongoDB. It newer use MongoDB `save` command, only `insert` and `update`.

Probably, mongoose only checks the status of `insert`/`update` operation.

I can see two options for you.

**1.** Remove `_id` before calling `new Card` constructor:

```
delete card._id;
var newCard = new Card(card);
```

or, if `card` is a `mongoose` document:

```
card_data = card.toObject();
delete card_data._id;
var newCard = new Card(card_data);
```

**2.** Set new `_id` field instead of removing it:

```
newCard._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

Comment: The first method did not work for me but the second one did. Thanks!